# Hide material by intersecting it with an object

Tags: materials, bezier-curves

Is there a way to hide or transform one material to another where the object with said materials intersects with another object? [image]

I created the connections between particles with the BTracer addon, which generates a 3D curve object, so booleans don't work. I would like to hide the traced lines with an object like the one in the image.

Comment: It looks lik you are using Eevee, I don't think it's straight up possible there, but in Cycles you can.